# Get details of installed java version using python

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to use subprocess to check if java is installed and also check if it's the right version. From the documentation you can map the output to variable and be able to use but it's not working for java. For example when I do `li = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-la", "."])` I get the output stored in li and nothing is shown on the console. But when I do `jd = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"])` this is what is shown on the terminal

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

and jd is empty.

Comment: `java -version` prints to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the results into `jd` by capturing standard error in the result to stdout:

```
jd = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"],
              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sometimes documentation is just not clear/enough for newbies.